# Why $('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"][value="true"]') and $('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"]) are defferent?

Tags: jquery

I use JQuery to get the same element by two ways, `$('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"][value="true"]')`  and `$('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"])[0]`, 
Here are the results in the console

```
$('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"][value="true"]')
r.fn.init [input#test, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
$('input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"]')[0]
<input type=​"radio" name=​"ShowAvatarRdo" id=​"test" value=​"true" checked=​"checked">​
```

It seems the types of the results are different, why?

Comment: If the checkbox isn't checked the first will return an empty jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one checkbox, the selectors `input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"]` and `input[name="ShowAvatarRdo"][value="true"]` return the same **array of elements**.

In the first case, you take the entire array, in the second case, you take the first element.

If you put `[0]` after both you'll get the exact same result, or if you do not take the first element, you'll get both times the entire array (of 1 element) :)